# Extract Bom Vocabulary IBM ODM in rule designer

Tags: eclipse, rule-engine, business-rules, vocabulary, ibm-odm

Hi all i am new to IBM ODM Rule designer i need to export all the vocabulary tab to be exported to a document is there smart to do it instead of copying manually.

Please find the attachment of screenshot highlighted with red color.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach for extracting this vocabulary is to search for your *.voc files in your project.  Inside these text files, you will find lines like:

com.model.BillingItemExtender.addChargeToTotalCharge(com.model.BillingItem,java.math.BigDecimal)#phrase.action = add a charge of  {1} to the total charge of {0}

The vocabulary is everything after the equal sign.  Use your tool of choice to parse these lines with a regex and output the vocabulary.